# Repeating animation on SwiftUI Image

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Given the following `struct`:

```
struct PeopleList : View {
    @State var angle: Double = 0.0
    @State var isAnimating = true

    var foreverAnimation: Animation {
        Animation.linear(duration: 2.0)
            .repeatForever()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.isAnimating ? self.angle : 0.0))
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(self.foreverAnimation) {
                        self.angle += 10.0
                    }
                }
        })
    }
}
```

I was hoping that the `Image` would rotate clockwise and repeat until `self.isAnimating` is `false` although it's only animated once.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is possible solution for continuous progressing on appear & start/stop. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

[image: demo]

```
struct PeopleList : View {
    @State private var isAnimating = false
    @State private var showProgress = false
    var foreverAnimation: Animation {
        Animation.linear(duration: 2.0)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.showProgress.toggle() }, label: {
            if showProgress {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.isAnimating ? 360 : 0.0))
                    .animation(self.isAnimating ? foreverAnimation : .default)
                    .onAppear { self.isAnimating = true }
                    .onDisappear { self.isAnimating = false }
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
            }
        })
        .onAppear { self.showProgress = true }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm seems the new attribute value inside .animation could be the culprit why this does not work anymore even if i set the value to just UUID()

Comment: Using `.animation(..., value: isAnimating)` does work for me.

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE: There is a backspin involved while stopping the animation which is solved with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64318967/4869523) solution.

I think its this what you are looking for:

```
struct PeopleList : View {
    @State var angle: Double = 0.0
    @State var isAnimating = false
    
    var foreverAnimation: Animation {
        Animation.linear(duration: 2.0)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.isAnimating ? 360.0 : 0.0))
                .animation(self.foreverAnimation)
                .onAppear {
                    self.isAnimating = true
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. The only problem is that if `self.isAnimating` is set to `false` then the animation still continues to run. Is there a way to stop the animation completely if `self.isAnimating` is `false`?

Comment: Great! It's clever approach. @fuzz I think you can pass `nil` to the animation modifier when `isAnimating` is false otherwise your `foreverAnimation`.

Comment: Looks like we have to get rid of the "repeatForever" animation somehow like this .animation(self.isAnimating ? foreverAnimation : foreverAnimationNo). foreverAnimationNo would be a non repeating animation.

Comment: Or just .animation(self.isAnimating ? foreverAnimation : .none)

Comment: It is solved in [How to STOP Animation().repeatForever in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59829109/12299030)