# Remove animation on SwiftUI view?

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
@StateObject var model = MyViewModel()
@State private var showAnimation = false

...



if model.isPushing {
    Button(action: {
        model.abort()
    }) {
HStack {
Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .red))
                                            .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(showAnimation ? 360 : 0), anchor: .center)
                                            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: showAnimation)
                                            .onAppear {
                                                showAnimation.toggle()
                                            }
                                            .onDisappear {
                                                showAnimation = false
                                            }
       }

    }
}
```

When the model `isPushing` is set to true the view renders the button and the image animation kicks in because of the `showAnimation` state change in `onAppear`...

The problem is that if I press the button again, the animation seems to compound or something and as you can tell it does not run smoothly.

Looking at the attached gif of the animation you can see the first part is smooth. Then `model.isPushing` is set to false and the button goes away. Once the `model.isPushing` is set to true again, the animation jumps as you can see. Seems like the previous animation is still running to me.

All I want to do is to show the rotate animation on the image anytime it's visible.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

After trying different approaches it seemed to me that the old animation would stick around. I do not know why, and I would love to understand why that is. I would think that when `model.sPushing` is set to false this part of the view would be teared down and done. But, there's something else going on.

I thought that setting the `duration` to `0` when the `showAnimation` is set to false would stop the problem. As of now, things work great by using this code:

```
Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath")
                                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                                            .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(showAnimation ? 360 : 0), anchor: .center)
                                            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: showAnimation ? 1.5 : 0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: showAnimation)
                                            .onAppear {
                                                showAnimation = true
                                            }
                                            .onDisappear {
                                                showAnimation = false
                                            }
```

So, when `showAnimation` is false I set the duration to 0. That allows the possible incoming animation to not have one underneath already running. I don't like this solution. I don't have a good grip on this yet and if somebody can provide more information and possible a cleaner solution please pitch in.

I'm quite experienced in Core Animation in UIKit, and I come from a mindset of being able to remove any animation I want from a layer before adding another one etc...

I would like to understand how to properly remove an animation from a `View` before triggering another one. At least that is what makes sense in my head as of now.

This link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59829109/12299030

provided by Asperi might very well be another great way of doing it, but, to be honest I can't make much sense out of it either.

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? It's not clear what's specifically going on inside `model.abort()` and how it's connected to `isPushing`, but by including the relevant code to make this compile, it would make it all clear.

Comment: model.abort() simply calls a function on a separate part of the app and then sets the ‘isPushing’ @Published Boolean in the model to false.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59829109/12299030?