How to make a running SwiftUI animation stop?
I have a animation that loops forever and it works great for what I have, but I want to make it stop and resume the animation as soon as I trigger something in my code. This is my example:
import SwiftUI

struct AnimatedImage: View {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool    
    @State private var rotation = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "arrow.up")
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(
                    .linear(duration: 1)
                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                        rotation = 360
                    }
            }
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    @Previewable @State var isEnabled = false
    
    VStack {
        Button("rotating: \(isEnabled)") {
            isEnabled.toggle()
        }
        
        Spacer().frame(height: 20)
        
        AnimatedImage(isAnimating: $isEnabled)
    }
}

What I want to do is to make the animation stop when $isEnabled is false, so I tried the following:
.onChange(of: isAnimating) { old, new in
    if new {
        withAnimation(
            .linear(duration: 1)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                rotation = 360
        }
    } else {
        withAnimation(nil) {
             rotation = rotation
        }
    }
}

Anyways the animation will not stop and loops forever. How to make it stop and resume after some event?

You're in luck this question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648245/swiftui-pause-resume-rotation-animation

See also SwiftUI Animation finish animation cycle
