# rotationEffect in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want my picture to rotate slowly in a circle, clockwise. I tried but I couldn't.

```
HStack {
    image("img")
        .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62080312/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `rotationEffect` and animate it using `repeatForever(autoreverses: false)`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var degrees: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: degrees))
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
        }
        .onAppear {
            degrees = 360
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the picture continues to move up and down. @pawello2222

Comment: @metaflor22 Then please add more details to your answer. The image in the answer above doesn't move up nor down.