# Animate text on and off screen in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to animate text to make it scroll across the screen, (using it to make a stock app), I am unable to get it to go completely off the screen can someone please help...

This is what I have so far

```
let text = "Some text to animate"
private var is = true
var body: some View {
VStack { 
Text(text)
.fixedSize()
.frame(width: 100, alignment: is ? .trailing : .leading)
.animation(Animation.linear(duration: 5).repeatForever())
}
```

Comment: This is SwiftUI code. You should use the SwiftUI tag, not Swift. (or at least **also** add the SwiftUI tag.)

Comment: Are you trying to make something like a news ticker?

Comment: Please try out my code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77397865/3013992

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to use single Text with .move asymmetric transition.

Here is a simplified demo. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { gp in
        VStack {
            Text(text)
                .fixedSize()
                .frame(width: gp.size.width + textWidth, alignment: .trailing)
                .id(go)
                .transition(transition)
                .onAppear{ go.toggle() }
                .animation(animation, value: go)
        }
    }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
}
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestRoundTripText.swift)

Comment: Yes, toggle `go` back and switch animation to `.default`, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62080312/12299030.

Comment: It seems that just stops the animation whereas I am trying to make it pause so that if resumed it continues from where it left off

Answer (score 1):

like this? It shifts the text using .offset if `go` is true.

```
    let text = "Some text to animate"
    @State private var go = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
                .fixedSize()
                .frame(width: 100)
                .offset(x: go ? 300 : 0, y: 0)
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 3).repeatForever(), value: go)
                .onAppear{self.go.toggle()}
        }
    }
```