# SwiftUI marquee sample

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to find swiftUI code implementing marquee which shows only the rolling text content inside the text view.  Text rolling outside to the left and right of the text view will not be shown.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72719886/12299030?

Comment: Yes, I am able to use clipped() to masked off unwanted content.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Put the text in an overlay of your box and animate the `.offset` to scroll the text.  Add `.clipped()` to the box to clip any text that appears outside of the box:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textoffset = 300.0
    
    let text = "This is a test of scrolling text.  This is only a test."
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .frame(width: 250, height: 100)
            .overlay (
                Text(text)
                    .fixedSize()
                    .offset(x: textoffset, y: 0)
            )
            .animation(.linear(duration: 10)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: textoffset)
            .clipped()
            .onAppear {
                textoffset = -300.0
            }
    }
}
```

---

[image: scrolling text in a box]

Comment: Is it possible to set marquee effect text in Lock Screen Inline widget?

Comment: Do you have any tips how to have marquee without any gap or spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try out my automatic horizontal scrolling text, also called marquee text or text ticker, without gaps and spaces.

```
//MarqueeText.swift

import SwiftUI

struct MarqueeText : View {
    private let text: String
    
    private let font: UIFont
    
    private let separation: String
    
    private let scrollDurationFactor: CGFloat
    
    @State private var animate = false
    
    @State private var size = CGSize.zero
    
    private var scrollDuration: CGFloat {
        stringWidth * scrollDurationFactor
    }
    
    private var stringWidth: CGFloat {
        (text + separation).widthOfString(usingFont: font)
    }
    
    private func shouldAnimated(_ width: CGFloat) -> Bool {
        width < stringWidth
    }
    
    static private let defaultSeparation = " ++++ "
    
    static private let defaultScrollDurationFactor: CGFloat = 0.02
    
    init(_ text: String,
         font: UIFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body, compatibleWith: .current),
         separation: String = defaultSeparation,
         scrollDurationFactor: CGFloat = defaultScrollDurationFactor)         {
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        self.separation = separation
        self.scrollDurationFactor = scrollDurationFactor
        self.animate = animate
    }
    
    init(_ text: String,
         textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle,
         separation: String = defaultSeparation,
         scrollDurationFactor: CGFloat = defaultScrollDurationFactor)
    {
        self.init(text, font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle, compatibleWith: .current), separation: separation, scrollDurationFactor: scrollDurationFactor)
    }
    
    var body : some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let shouldAnimated = shouldAnimated(geometry.size.width)
            
            scrollItem(offset: self.animate ? -stringWidth : 0)
                .onAppear() {
                    size = geometry.size
                    if shouldAnimated  {
                        self.animate = true
                    }
                }
            
            if shouldAnimated{
                scrollItem(offset: self.animate ? 0 : stringWidth)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func scrollItem(offset: CGFloat) -> some View {
        Text(text + separation)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .font(Font(uiFont: font))
            .offset(x: offset)
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: scrollDuration).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: animate)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
           
    }
}

private extension String {
    
    func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
        return size.width
    }
}

private extension Font {
    init(uiFont: UIFont) {
        self = Font(uiFont as CTFont)
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            
            MarqueeText(text, textStyle: .body, separation: " **** ")
        }
        .frame(height: 64)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
}
```

[image]