# Constant animation speed based on length

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an animation:

```
private var animation: Animation {
        .linear
            .speed(0.1)
            .delay(2)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
}
```

which I will use for a custom scroll view I have by attaching this animation to it.  This way, the scroll speed will be very fast for long texts, and slow for small texts. Is there any way to have a constant speed for auto scrolling, regardless of how long the text is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI marquee sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73381978/swiftui-marquee-sample)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the animation speed a function of the length being scrolled. For example:

> speed = 10 / scrolledLength

Assuming you are performing horizontal scroll, you can use a `GeometryReader` to get the view width and another to find the width of the string. The length to be scrolled is the difference between them. If in fact you are performing vertical scroll then of course it is the heights you are interested in.

Here is an example to show it working. Each scroll section consists of a base view that shows the text at full size on one line, but hidden. This establishes the footprint. The visible version is shown as an overlay, with animation operating on the x-offset.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var animate = false

    private let shortBanner = "StackOverflow: Constant animation speed based on length"
    private let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    private func animation(scrolledLength: CGFloat) -> Animation {
        .linear
        .speed(10.0 / max(1, abs(scrolledLength)))
        .delay(2)
        .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
    }

    private func autoScrollView(key: String, viewWidth: CGFloat) -> some View {
        Text(LocalizedStringKey(key))
            .lineLimit(1)
            .fixedSize()
            .hidden()
            .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Text(LocalizedStringKey(key))
                        .offset(x: animate ? viewWidth - proxy.size.width : 0)
                        .animation(
                            animation(scrolledLength: proxy.size.width - viewWidth),
                            value: animate
                        )
                }
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
                autoScrollView(key: shortBanner, viewWidth: proxy.size.width)
                autoScrollView(key: loremIpsum, viewWidth: proxy.size.width)
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .onAppear { animate = true }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

For a solution where the reverse animation goes faster, see [Swift UI - Animating long line of text to scroll left and right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76463622/20386264).