# Marquee scrolling when row focused - tvOS

Tags: swiftui, tvos

This is on tvOS and using swiftUI

I have a simple side panel that displays a list of category names.

When the user focus's on one of the rows, I would like to make it scroll the text (a marquee effect).

There are options for marquee but they scroll regardless of focus and applies to all items in my foreach.

```
if displaySidePanel {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                ScrollView() {
                    ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { cat in
                        VStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text(“just a test) {
                                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                                Text(cat[0])
                                 .font(.caption)
                             }
                             .padding()
                         }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 40)
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 400)
}
```

Is it possible?  thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72719886/12299030?

Comment: It’s one of the many methods Ive seen to scroll the text, but my issue is I want only the Text() to scroll when the text row has focus.  Using that method means all text() will be scrolled regardless of focus.  Thanks

Comment: on focus or on appear is only a action to activate effect, it can be any and does not matter